# Python Tkinter ttk treeview columns padding plus multiple lines

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm having an issue I'm coding a Tkinter GUI using python. I'm trying to give the left side of my Tkinter ttk treeview columns a padding of 10 pixels. I looked at the tkinter documentation but nothing.

The final issue I am having is  I need the text inside my column to expand to multiple lines if the text passes x amount of characters per a line.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks 
I'm looking forward to some help

Comment: What have you tried so far (Source Code)? Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For the padding - there is a block about padding of elements inside the [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html).

Comment: Note that in 3.x, 'Tkinter' is 'tkinter'.

Comment: Ok regarding the columns padding this is what I tried  treeview.column("status",width=100, anchor="center",padx=4)  adn regarding the wrap length I tried this treeview.column("status",width=100, anchor="center",wraplength=5)     but these options don't work with the current ttk objects

Comment: @LogicalNonsense Did you find any solutions?